# multi store views single checkout and login?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout, multistore, login

So I got it setup and am understanding the structure better.
I followed a few tutorials i found online and finally goto multiple domains pointed to multiple stored views with different themes.

The reason I went this way is it was my understanding they could all share the same cart and the products would carry from site/store view to next site/store view remain in the cart until they want to checkout.

And that they would share the same accounts regardless of which store view they logged into and that they would only have to register/log in once across all store views?

doesnt seem to be working for me though.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pay attention to two things:

1. If the store views are assigned to different websites, set the "share customer accounts" setting in *System > Configuration > Customer > Customer Configuration* to "Global"

   [image]
2. To keep the session when switching between stores **on different domains**, enable "Use SID on Frontend" in *System > Configuration > General > Web*:

   [image]

Comment: I have these settings setup accordingly and it still doesnt work, does it matter which domain they register at? the primary core site or the store view site?

Comment: No, that only matters for the things like the language of emails sent to the user.

Comment: Okay  so every thing is setup as above but what isnt happening is that once they log into one domain they should not have to log into the additional store view domains which they have to, and its not sharing the cart items accross all domains, essentially I would like it so if they land at any of the five domains/storeviews they would be able to log in and if they goto another domain/storeview they would already be loggged in, and in addition they could add a item continue to next domain/storeview add another item etc. until they checkout freedom-performance.com and coyoteperformanceparts.com

Comment: I would be willing to hire someone provide a bounty etc. to get this working as needed. Let me know if your interested. Thanks

Comment: also what is the preffered session model for this kind of setup vuia files or SQL?